# copy a list of data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following situation:

1) a list of data tables

2) For testing purposes I *deliberately* want to (deeply) copy the whole list including the data tables

3) I want to take some element from the copied list and add a new column.

Here is the code:

```
library(data.table)
x = data.table(aaa = c(1,2))
y = data.table(bbb = c(1,2))
z = list(x,y)
zz = copy(z)

v = zz[[1]]
v = v[, newColumn := 1]
```

Now Im getting the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(res, , `:=`(xxx, TRUE)) : 
(converted from warning) Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed
by taking a copy of the whole table so that := can add this new column 
by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R 
(or been created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid key<-, 
names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole 
data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames 
and ?setattr. Also, in R<=v3.0.2, list(DT1,DT2) copied the entire DT1 
and DT2 (R's list() used to copy named objects); please upgrade to 
R>v3.0.2 if that is biting. If this message doesn't help, please report 
to datatable-help so the root cause can be fixed.
```

I dont understand precisely how the copy calls are handled by R and how they are passed to data.table but isnt it like so: (?)

If someone explicitely uses the copy function then he/she is aware of the fact that there exists a difference between 'by-value' and 'by-reference'. So he/she should be handed out the true copy of the object.

Hence, I am of the opinion that there should not be any error and I consider it as a 'bug' that the error occurs nonetheless. Is that correct?

FW

Comment: What version of `R` and `data.table` are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`copy()` is for copying `data.table`'s. You are using it to copy a `list`. Try..

```
zz <- lapply(z,copy)
zz[[1]][ , newColumn := 1 ]
```

---

Using your original code, you will see that applying `copy()` to the `list` does not make a copy of the original `data.table`. They are still referenced by the same location in memory:

```
library(data.table)
x = data.table(aaa = c(1,2))
y = data.table(bbb = c(1,2))
z = list(x,y)
zz = copy(z)

#  Both zz$x and z$x are the same object:
.Internal(inspect(zz$x))
#  @7fd58a079778 00 NILSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(2)] 
.Internal(inspect(z$x))
#  @7fd58a079778 00 NILSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(2)]
```

Comment: This is nice answer, but I'm struggling with your *"`copy` is for copying `data.table`s"*. Actually you can use `copy` successfully on *any* R object (including lists, for example `l <- list(1) ; l2 <- copy(l) ; .Internal(inspect(l)) ; .Internal(inspect(l2))`), it's just OP didn't use it properly for `data.table`s in this particular case.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I did notice that too, but just because it *works* on other objects doesn't mean that it was *intended* to. If that were the case then the documentation should really be updated because it states that for `copy(x)`, `x` is a `data.table`. So as I see it, `copy()` is defined and documented to work in a certain way on `data.tables`, anything else is user risk/error.

Comment: I think we should make a PR then and fix the documentations :)

Comment: Ah thats weird... then allow me to ask: why does it work on other objects when it does clearly not work on other objects? :-)

Comment: You need @Arun to explain how the mechanics of `copy` work and what it was and was not designed to do...

Comment: @FabianWerner, `copy()` was intended to work with all objects, since it's just a call to `duplicate()` from R's C-API. However, we hadn't anticipated the list-of-data.tables usage, as if you look at `copy()`, it has a call to `alloc.col()`. I think we need to fix the case of list of data.tables, or restrict to atomic vectors / data.frames / data.tables and / or document it. Could you please file an issue on github page with the title "copy() on list of data.tables issue" and simply linking to this post? Thanks.

Comment: @Arun: Done. (and thanks again for this wonderful package :-))