# How to make a list of multiple copies of the same data.table without looping? (and not assigning by reference)

Tags: r, list, data.table, copy, assign

I was wondering if there is a cleaner one-liner to make a list of multiple copies of the same data.table object **not by reference**, avoiding the need for a loop.

The use case is that I want to create `m` multiple data.tables that will differ only by the values of a single column. Hence I would make a list with equal objects, then iterate over every data.table and modify the values of one column, ending up with `m` different data.tables.

Currently my clunky inelegant approach is:

```
library(data.table)

  # Load data and create data.table
data("airquality")
dt <- data.table(airquality)

  # Number of copies
m = 3

  # Pre-allocate
dt_list <- list()

  # Populate the list with `m` copies of the original data.table
for (i in 1:m) {
  dt_list[[i]] <- copy(dt)
}

# Assign by reference within each data.table
for (i in 1:m) {
  dt_list[[i]][, Ozone := rep(i)]
}

dt_list
# [[1]]
# Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1:     1     190  7.4   67     5   1
# 2:     1     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 3:     1     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 4:     1     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5:     1      NA 14.3   56     5   5

# [[2]]
# Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1:     2     190  7.4   67     5   1
# 2:     2     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 3:     2     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 4:     2     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5:     2      NA 14.3   56     5   5

# [[3]]
# Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1:     3     190  7.4   67     5   1
# 2:     3     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 3:     3     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 4:     3     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5:     3      NA 14.3   56     5   5
```

Other similar questions consider different data.table objects or [they assign by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30977679/10930406), so that all copies are also changed when one is changed. For example by doing `dt_list <- rep(list(dt), m)`, all `Ozone` columns are filled with `3`s.

Comment: `rep(list(dt), m)` creates logical copies but all point to the same object. You can use  `replicate(m, copy(dt), FALSE)`  to create `m` different copies (objects).

Comment: Why have multiple copies in the first place?

Comment: @s_baldur As I described, I want to have multiple equal datasets to then modify the values of a single column, e.g. a multiple imputation scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve your problem:

```
dt_list = lapply(1:3, \(i) copy(dt)[, Ozone := i])
# or
dt_list = lapply(1:3, \(i) set(copy(dt), j="Ozone", value=i))

[[1]]
     Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
     <int>   <int> <num> <int> <int> <int>
  1:     1     190   7.4    67     5     1
  2:     1     118   8.0    72     5     2
  3:     1     149  12.6    74     5     3
  4:     1     313  11.5    62     5     4
  5:     1      NA  14.3    56     5     5
 ---                                      
149:     1     193   6.9    70     9    26
150:     1     145  13.2    77     9    27
151:     1     191  14.3    75     9    28
152:     1     131   8.0    76     9    29
153:     1     223  11.5    68     9    30

[[2]]
     Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
     <int>   <int> <num> <int> <int> <int>
  1:     2     190   7.4    67     5     1
  2:     2     118   8.0    72     5     2
  3:     2     149  12.6    74     5     3
  4:     2     313  11.5    62     5     4
  5:     2      NA  14.3    56     5     5
 ---                                      
149:     2     193   6.9    70     9    26
150:     2     145  13.2    77     9    27
151:     2     191  14.3    75     9    28
152:     2     131   8.0    76     9    29
153:     2     223  11.5    68     9    30

[[3]]
     Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
     <int>   <int> <num> <int> <int> <int>
  1:     3     190   7.4    67     5     1
  2:     3     118   8.0    72     5     2
  3:     3     149  12.6    74     5     3
  4:     3     313  11.5    62     5     4
  5:     3      NA  14.3    56     5     5
 ---                                      
149:     3     193   6.9    70     9    26
150:     3     145  13.2    77     9    27
151:     3     191  14.3    75     9    28
152:     3     131   8.0    76     9    29
153:     3     223  11.5    68     9    30
```

Comment: This is also a nice alternative but ended up using `replicate(m, copy(dt), FALSE)` as in your comment and then changing within each replicate by reference, as some quick benchmarking showed this was faster. Thanks!